# How to Handle Application Exit/Close

Tags: wpf

How do you handle closing an application in a WPF Prism application?  A user can close an application by either going to File->Exit or by closing the main application window/shell.  I handle the File->Exit using a DelegateCommand and then calling Application.Current.Shutdown() in the ExecuteMethod.

1. Is calling Application.Current.Shutdown() the proper way to close
   the application in the MainWIndowViewModel?
2. How do do handle the OnExit case?  How do you call back into the MainWidowViewModel when this happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is calling Application.Current.Shutdown() the proper way to close the application in the MainWIndowViewModel?

Essentially, yes, but I'd hide it behind some `IShutdownService` so I can mock it more easily when writing the tests for `MainWindowViewModel`.

> How do do handle the OnExit case? How do you call back into the MainWidowViewModel when this happens?

You can use [`EventToCommand`](https://prismlibrary.com/docs/wpf/interactivity/event-to-command.html) or [`InvokeCommandAction`](https://github.com/microsoft/XamlBehaviorsWpf/wiki/InvokeCommandAction) to call a command when the `Closing` and/or `Closed` events of the `MainWindow` happen.